# Javascript regex not matching consistently with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, unicode

I've noticed an unusual behaviour in Javascript regex parsing.

The following example illustrates the issue.

If the character "a" is expressed via its hex representation `0x61` (in unicode `\u61`), I expect a match using the following regex:

```
v‌‌ar a = String.fromCharCode(0x61) // "a"
a.match(/^[\u61]$/g) // does not match
```

It does not match.

Yet weirdly, the expression below does match:

```
a.match(/^[\u61-\u61]$/g) // does match!
```

Note: This may be a Chrome-specific Javascript bug.

Comment: Why not use `\x61`? Note that with ES6+ you may also use `a.match(/^\u{61}$/u)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Use a **four-digit** unicode identifier (including the redundant bits).

```
a.match(/^[\u0061]$/g) // matches
```

You could also use curly brace notation. If matching unicode of 5-digits or more, curl braces are required. Note the `u` flag, which enables curly brace support.

```
a.match(/^[\u{1f601}]$/ug)
```

Comment: This still won't catch all unicode characters..  eg. `"".match(/^\u1f60d/)` will not work.  But `"".match(/^\u{1f60d}/u)` does.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my solution!